# expand arguments from array containing double quotes

Tags: arrays, bash, quotes

I want to call a program with **arguments built from an array** in bash.

I want bash to call:

```
echo -arg1=simple -arg2="some spaces"
```

from `array=(echo -arg1=simple "-arg2=\"some spaces\"")` or similar (I can adjust the way the items are created).

#### Problem

With `"${array[@]}"` bash calls:

```
echo -arg1=simple '-arg2="some spaces"'
```

But I do not want the single quotes. How to build and expand the array correctly?

#### Example code

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

array=()
array+=(echo)
array+=(-arg1=simple)
array+=("-arg2=\"some spaces\"")

"${array[@]}"
"${array[*]}"
${array[@]}
${array[*]}
```

#### Resulting calls

```
echo -arg1=simple '-arg2="some spaces"'
'echo -arg1=simple -arg2="some spaces"'
echo -arg1=simple '-arg2="some' 'spaces"'
echo -arg1=simple '-arg2="some' 'spaces"'
```

Comment: Why are you keeping `echo` in your array?

Comment: To make the example simpler, I could have written `echo "${array[@]}"` and omit it from the array.

Comment: The single quotes aren't actually doing anything; that's just how the `-x` option chooses to display the second argument. `"${array[@]}"` is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do it like this, no need to keep `echo` inside the array:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

array=()
array+=(-arg1=simple)
array+=(-arg2="some spaces")

echo "${array[@]}"
```

This results with a call to `echo` which receives two words as arguments, `-arg1=simple` and `-arg2="some spaces"`, as if you wrote:

```
echo -arg1=simple -arg2="some spaces"
```

Alternatively, you can define your array in one line, with `declare`:

```
declare -a array=(-arg1=simple -arg2="some spaces")
```

To check how it will be expanded, you can use `printf` (we use `==` here just to clearly show the beginning and ending of each argument):

```
$ printf "==%s==\n" "${array[@]}"
==-arg1=simple==
==-arg2=some spaces==
```

Note the importance of quotes around `${array[@]}`. They ensure that each element in the array is expanded into only one word (like if quoted in shell before expansion). Compare that with:

```
$ printf "==%s==\n" ${array[@]}
==-arg1=simple==
==-arg2=some==
==spaces==
```

**Update**. If you want to expand it to exactly `-arg2="some spaces"` (not sure why you would want it, though), just wrap it inside a single quotes on definition:

```
$ declare -a array=(-arg1=simple '-arg2="some spaces"')
$ echo "${array[@]}"
-arg1=simple -arg2="some spaces"
$ printf "==%s==\n" "${array[@]}"
==-arg1=simple==
==-arg2="some spaces"==
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip with printf, but I want it expand to `-arg2="some spaces"` and not `-arg2=some spaces`

Comment: When I wrap it like so: `echo "echo ${array[@]}" | source /dev/stdin` bash seems to call `echo -arg1=simple '-arg2=some spaces'` which is not exactly what I'm searching but cmake seems to accept that (`cmake .. -bla -bla '-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-bla -bla'`).

Comment: Your update would work, but in the real code `some spaces` is `${cxx_flags[*]}` and with the single quotes this variable does not get expanded :/

Comment: @bibermann, that's crucial detail. Please update the question, because that changes everything. And please tell up **exactly** what are you trying to do. Help us so we can help you!

Comment: CMake also accepts the version with single quotes I got in the question. I haven't tried that, it just looked wrong. Nevertheless, your update answeres the non-specific question, so I accept that.

Comment: CMake does not like it anymore. I opened a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45338369/call-program-with-arguments-from-an-array-containing-items-from-another-array-wr

Answer (score 5):

`"${array[@]}"` is correct. The `-x` option simply chooses a canonical way to display values that require quoting, and `'-arg2="some spaces"'` is equivalent to `"-arg2=\"some spaces\""`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: I don't want the double quotes escaped inside. The `echo` produces the command line I want but I need bash to call that not to display that.