# What is the proper syntax for a single quoted param within a pair of double quotes (bash)

Tags: bash, docker

I have a bash script that is custom tool for running docker containers. I can't show entire script. In the following scenario:

```
    local dockerArgs=(
            "--restart=on-failure:5"
            "--memory 512m"
            "--cpu-shares 1024"
            "--pids-limit 100"
            "--health-cmd='stat /etc/passwd'"
            "--security-opt=no-new-privileges"
            "-v /containers/logs/:/containers/logs/"
            "-v /etc/conf/prometheus/:/etc/conf/prometheus/"
    )
```

, all the params are processed correctly except the health-cmd param. It the only one with the single-quoted value. The script fails due to the above syntax for health-cmd. Grateful for any ideas to fix. Thanks

Comment: Remove the single quotes and make sure you quote your expansion `"${dockerArgs[@]}"`

Comment: @jordanm I am already doing that: sudo docker run ${cloudArgs[@]} ${dockerArgs[@]} -e  ...

Comment: You are missing the quotes in your example. `sudo docker run "${cloudArgs[@]}" "${dockerArgs[@]}" -e`

Comment: You should also have `-v` be a separate array element from `/containers/logs:/containers/logs`; similarly, `--pids-limit` should be a separate array element from `100`.

Comment: Also, use `local -a` when defining an array.

Comment: @jordanm I now have:   "--health-cmd=stat /etc/passwd" , and 
        sudo docker run "${cloudArgs[@]}" "${dockerArgs[@]}" -e JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS}" --name "${applicationName}" -d -t ${dockerRegistry}/${containerName}:${version} ${opts[@]}

and it still is failing.

Comment: they are making me create a new question. claiming its a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45325659/expand-arguments-from-array-containing-double-quotes

Answer (score 1):

`--health-cmd='stat /etc/passwd'` and `"--health-cmd=stat /etc/passwd"` are equivalent words, each of which is equivalent to the *pair* of words `--health-cmd` and `stat /etc/passwd` to your program. You can write either

```
local dockerArgs=(
   ...
   --health-cmd 'stat /etc/passwd'
   ...
)
```

or

```
local dockerArgs=(
   ...
   "--health-cmd=stat /etc/passwd"  # or --health-cmd='stat /etc/passwd'
   ...
)
```

and

```
docker ... "${dockerArgs[@]}"
```

will work the same same either way.

Comment: Very much correct as far as it goes, but the `health-cmd` argument isn't the only one where the OP needs to fix their quoting. f/e, `"--cpu-shares 100"` should be `"--cpu-shares" "100"` or just `--cpu-shares 100`.

Comment: Hi. I tried both of the above and neither worked. Here is how the actual run command vars are expanded in:         # Start the container
        sudo docker run ${cloudArgs[@]} ${dockerArgs[@]} -e JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS}" --name "${applicationName}" -d -t ${dockerRegistry}/${containerName}:${version} ${opts[@]}

Comment: You aren't quoting the array expansions as instructed.

Comment: @chepner , I now have: "--health-cmd=stat /etc/passwd" , and sudo docker run "${cloudArgs[@]}" "${dockerArgs[@]}" -e JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS}" --name "${applicationName}" -d -t ${dockerRegistry}/${containerName}:${version} ${opts[@]} and it still is failing.

Comment: See Charles Duffy's comment: that's not the only option (or rather, pair of options) you have misquoted in the definition of the array.

Comment: E.g., either `(... "--memory" "512m" ...)` or `(... "--memory=512m")`, but not `(... "--memory 512m" ...)`.

Comment: @chepner  the memory param is not an issue. All params are processed correctly other than health-cmd. Charles addressed the params that are NOT causing me issues but not the one the isn't working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241828/discussion-between-timothy-clotworthy-and-chepner).